# Python TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. How to add 'bytes'?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, iptc, iptcinfo

I got an error `TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` when I use save, what to do to make it right?

I want to save in same image, not to create a new one.

```
from iptcinfo3 import IPTCInfo
import sys
imagename = 'horse.jpg'
info = IPTCInfo(imagename)
info['keywords'] = 'horse', 'brown', 'animal', 'nature'
info.save()
```

How to add 'bytes'? [Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/IPTCInfo3/) doesn't say anything?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this specific package before, but I believe the keywords should be a python list (I may be wrong)

Have you tried adding square brackerts around the keywords, like this?

```py
from iptcinfo3 import IPTCInfo
import sys
imagename = 'horse.jpg'
info = IPTCInfo(imagename)
info['keywords'] = ['horse', 'brown', 'animal', 'nature']
info.save()
```